# UITableView pagination with server API

Tags: swift, api, uitableview, pagination

I want to apply a pagination in a UITableView.In the API from server the number of total pages is not known only the current page and the limit per page.Any best practises how to display the loading cell at the UITableView.Currently in my implementation I'm checking the current page if this page is less than array items then display the loading cell.Any ideas?

```
api.fetch(["page": 1]) { result
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.showCell = self.currentPage < self.items.count
      ....
      completion(nil)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == data.count {
            getData()
        }
    }
```

You can use this method. This method get data from API before last table view cell  load.

You can visit this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview) for more info.